# Debugging of image processing code

Tags: c++, debugging, logging, image-processing, computer-vision

What kind of debugging is available for image processing/computer vision/computer graphics applications in C++? What do you use to track errors/partial results of your method?

What I have found so far is just one tool for online and one for offline debugging:

1. [bmd](http://www.theycamefromhollywood.com/bmd/): attaches to a running process and enables you to view a block of memory as an image
2. [imdebug](http://www.billbaxter.com/projects/imdebug/): enables printf-style of debugging

Both are quite outdated and not really what I would expect.

What would seem useful for offline debugging would be some style of *image logging*, lets say a set of commands which enable you to write images together with text (probably in the form of HTML, maybe hierarchical), easy to switch off at both compile and run time, and the least obtrusive it can get.

The output could look like this (output from our simple tool):
http://tsh.plankton.tk/htmldebug/d8egf100-RF-SVM-RBF_AC-LINEAR_DB.html

Are you aware of some code that goes in this direction?

I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: This is a very general question with a very wide scope. Please try to narrow it down to specific kind of debugging you are referring to. Are you asking about how to collect performance statistics, how to measure processing quality, how to see partial results or how to debug your C/C++ code?

Comment: Actually, I am interested in a way how to include images as a type of information in a debugging process in a principled way. So except for performance statistics (which do not make sense when saving lots of images for debugging purposes) all usage scenarios you list are perfectly valid.

Comment: Judging by the answer of @phresnel it seems you are right and I should set it straight. I will try to produce a sample output to explain better.

Answer (score 3):

Coming from a ray tracing perspective, maybe some of those visual methods are also useful to you (it is one of my plans to write a short paper about such techniques):

1. **Surface Normal Visualization.** Helps to find surface discontinuities. (no image handy, the look is very much reminiscent of normal maps)

   `color <- rgb (normal.x+0.5, normal.y+0.5, normal.z+0.5)`
2. **Distance Visualization.** Helps to find surface discontinuities and errors in finding a nearest point. (image taken from an abandoned ray tracer of mine)

   `color <- (intersection.z-min)/range, ...`

   [image]
3. **Bounding Volume Traversal Visualization.** Helps visualizing a bounding volume hierarchy or other hierarchical structures, and helps to see the traversal hotspots, like a code profiler (e.g. Kd-trees). (tbp of http://ompf.org/forum coined the term *Kd-vision*).

   [image]
   [image]

   color <- number_of_traversal_steps/f
4. **Bounding Box Visualization** (image from picogen or so, some years ago). Helps to verify the partitioning.

   [image]

   color <- const
5. **Stereo.** Maybe useful in your case as for the real stereographic appearance. I must admit I never used this for debugging, but when I think about it, it could prove really useful when implementing new types of 3d-primitives and -trees (image from gladius, which was an attempt to unify realtime and non-realtime ray tracing)

   [image]

   You just render two images with slightly shifted position, focusing on some point
6. **Hit-or-not visualization.** May help to find epsilon errors. (image taken from metatrace)

   [image: http://th01.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/f/2010/309/b/0/debugging_a_c___in_s_anity_by_phresnel-d327c6w.png]

   if (hit) color = const_a;
   else     color = const_b
7. **Some hybrid of several techniques.**

   1. Linear interpolation: `lerp(debug_a, debug_b)`
   2. Interlacing: `if(y%2==0) debug_a else debug_b`
   3. Any combination of ideas, for example the color-tone from *Bounding Box Visualization*, but with actual scene-intersection and lighting applied

---

You may find some more glitches and debugging imagery on http://phresnel.org , http://phresnel.deviantart.com , http://picogen.deviantart.com , and maybe http://greenhybrid.deviantart.com (an old account).

Comment: ...pretty pictures these are:) And thank you for the references.

Although it rather solves how to visualize the data and obtain an image, not how to organize lots of output images to analyze the code.

Comment: Thx :) @tsh: Though your question included "computer vision/computer graphics", and I thought this question-thread might be interesting for future reference. Image-debugging is really a seldom topic.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I prefer to dump bytearray of currently processed image as raw data triplets and run Imagemagick to create png from it with number e.g   img01.png. In this way i can trace the algorithms very easy. Imagemagick is run from the function in the program using system call. This make possible do debug without using any external libs for image formats.

Another option, if you are using Qt is to work with QImage and use img.save("img01.png") from time to time like a printf is used for debugging.

Comment: Just saving an image as PNG is easy, as you point out, one can use some high-level library to achieve that. I am rather asking about how to handle a situation where you have some textual or other data that accompanies the image, and especially in cases where there are huge numbers of images produced with some hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit primitive compared to what you are looking for, but i have done what you suggested in your OP using standard logging and by writing image files. typically, the logging and signal export processes and staging exist in unit tests.

signals are given identifiers (often input filename), which may be augmented (often process name or stage).

for development of processors, it's quite handy.

adding html for messages would be simple. in that context, you could produce viewable html output easily - you would not need to generate any html, just use html template files and then insert the messages.

i would just do it myself (as i've done multiple times already for multiple signal types) if you get no good referrals.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt Creator you can watch image modification while stepping through the code in the normal C++ debugger, see e.g. http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/04/22/peek-and-poke-vol-3/

Comment: It is a pity that it depends on Qt, otherwise it would be quite useful. Anyhow thank you for the link.